# Some extra padding in link on press

Tags: css

I didn't find any solution of my problem. I have image in link. When I press it then the image move down about a few pixels. Do you have idea how to remove this behavior?

It is code of link:

### HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.cpm" title="" class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" title=""/>
</a>
```

### CSS

```
    .logo {
        margin-top: 30px;
        display: block;
    }

    .logo img {
        width: 150px;
    }
```

I add border to logo

[image: I add border to logo]

and when I press on it then I see

[image: and when I press on it then I see]

Comment: please add code that you have tried

Comment: Please add relevant code to your issue. Currently we cannot help if we cannot see the issue

Comment: I recommend using a [CSS reset file](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+reset).

Comment: The problem is definitely not in the code you provided. Check http://jsfiddle.net/sSm7S/. So you have to provide more code if you want us to help.

Comment: I am sorry. You have right. I had bug in some other command in my css and it generate this issue. Sorry and thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```